# No operations allowed after connection closed

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I'm getting this error from a Java application:

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection - [c3p0] Another 
error has occurred [     
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
No operations allowed after connection closed. ] which will not be 
reported to listeners!
```

The Java code:

```
try {
    sessionFactory.beginTransaction();
    //...
    sessionFactory.commitTransaction();
} catch (Exception e) {
    sessionFactory.rollbackTransaction();
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

The session factory:

```
try {
    sessionFactory.beginTransaction();
    ...
    sessionFactory.commitTransaction();
} catch (Exception e) {
    sessionFactory.rollbackTransaction();
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

public Transaction beginTransaction() throws HibernateException {
    try {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    } catch (HibernateException hex) {
        LOG.error(String.format("Unable to start database transaction due to exception: %s.", ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(hex)));
        throw hex;
    }
}

public void commitTransaction() throws HibernateException {
    LOG.debug("Committing database transaction.");
    try {
        if (sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
        } else {
            throw new HibernateException("Transaction is no longer Active.");
        }
    } catch (HibernateException hex) {
        LOG.error(String.format("Unable to commit due to exception: %s.", ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(hex)));
        throw hex;
    }
}

public void rollbackTransaction() throws HibernateException {
    LOG.debug("Trying to rollback database transaction after exception.");
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    try {
        if (session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        } else {
            throw new HibernateException("Transaction is no longer Active.");
        }
    } catch (HibernateException hex) {
        LOG.error(String.format("Unable to rollback due to exception: %s.", ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(hex)));
        throw hex;
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Hibernate and C3P0 settings:

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>

<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800 <!-- seconds --></prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">4</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">35</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">240 <!-- seconds --></prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">4</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</prop>
<prop key="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout">60000 <!-- milliseconds --></prop>
```

Not sure how the connection can be still in use and this error thrown.  What is causing this error?

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing all of the code, but are you closing the session after a successful commit? I don't see that in the code above. If not, you are exhausting your connection pool.

Comment: The session is automatically closed when the transaction is committed: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/Sessionsandtransactions?_sscc=t#jive_content_id_Transaction_demarcation_with_plain_JDBC.

Answer (score 3):

This Java method called executeQuery:

```
your_database_connection.createStatement().executeQuery(your_string_query);
```

will throw this Exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
No operations allowed after connection closed.
```

if you try to run it (executeQuery) after calling:

```
your_database_connection.close()
```

**What is happening**

Either you are trying to get a connection to the database and are not getting one, and are trying to run a query against it which fails.  Or you got a connection which suffered some problem and became closed, and you tried to run another query through it.

**The solution**

Assuming you lost the connection from network problems or something that isn't your fault, then put the code that attempts the query in a try/catch block, and on error wait 10 seconds and reconnect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

your idleConnectionTestPeriod is 240,it should less then the db waiting timeout value ,see the db config ,check the value is bigger than 240.